Does the VOLUME instruction in a Dockerfile create a volume or only specify a mountpoint?
https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#volume needs work.
"The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers."
Nowhere does it say "the volume needs to exist" OR "the build process will create it" when you have
VOLUME ["/etc/blue", "/var/cache/blah", "/var/lib/bar", "/var/log"]
in your Dockerfile. We know we can create volumes with 'docker volume create foo' but there's no indication of whether this is expected.

Dockerfile creates a image. That image can be distributed to other systems. The volume is defined in docker file, but created when you run an instance of a image. It seems to me that you're mixing different parts of docker. There's nothing unclear in the documentation; the mix up is entirely in your understanding of the various moving parts involved in the docker ecosystem.

A VOLUME directive:

Creates an anonymous volume at build time, so that any files placed into the volume mountpoint won't be included in the generated image. This volume is removed when the build completes.

Creates an anonymous volume at run time that will be removed when the container is removed, unless something (a volume or a bind mount) is explicitly mounted on this mountpoint.


For example, if we have:
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest
VOLUME /data
COPY <<EOF /data/testfile.txt
This is a test
EOF

Then:

We will find that the image does not contain /data/testfile.txt.

If we start a container without an explicit mount, as in:
docker run -it --rm testimage

While the container is running we will see:
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     952012ac54d9b9f7091f756940b4a5a60fa276e8fbce7a8892fc316272421613

But when the container exists, the volume will be removed.

If we explicitly mount a volume on the volume mountpoint:
docker run -it --rm -v myvolume:/data testimage

Then the anonymous volume is not created:
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     myvolume

And the volume is preserved when the container exits.


